# Как выполнить функцию после завершения изменения хука состояния?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Когда мы вызываем setState в классе, то можем передать колбек в последний аргумент, и колбек выполнится сразу после завершения изменения.

```
this.setState({}, () => { выполнится по завершении изменения })
```

Пример кода:

```
const foo = () => {
   setOpen(false);
   bar(); // эта функция должна быть выполнена сразу после setOpen, но setOpen - асинхронная функция
}
```

Вопрос: Как выполнить bar() сразу после завершения обновления хука через setOpen именно с аргументом false?

Comment: используйте `useEffect`, подпишитесь на изменение `*setOpen` и возвращайте `bar()` функцию

Comment: @meine тут тоже есть вопросы - нужно чтобы функция срабатывала именно если параметр === false, как тогда поступать?

Comment: сделайте проверку на `false` всего делов :)

Comment: А что делает bar ? это касается рендера или получения данных?

Comment: @NeedHate bar() - функция, которая проброшена из родителя. Она удаляет из DOM диалоговое окно, у которого состояние открытия/закрытия управляется хуком `[open, setOpen]`. Я хочу выполнять размонтирование окна сразу после его закрытия, чтобы сохранить плавность анимации закрывания окна

Comment: так может сделать анимацию, а потом коллбэком отправить изменение состояния? Еще проще, да, выше сказано, useEffect.

Comment: @NeedHate я использую Material-UI компоненты, там все анимации уже написаны за меня, не хочется такой большой велосипед строить. Да и дело даже не в контексте вопроса, частенько возникает проблема выполнения определенной функции после завершения изменения хука

Answer (score 0):

Асинхронная функция возвращает `Promise`, чтобы выполнить что-либо сразу после выполнения promise нужно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```
setOpen(false)
  .then(
    result => {
      // первая функция-обработчик - запустится при успешном завершении (resolve)
      // alert("setOpen resolve() return " + result);
      bar();
    },
    error => {
      // вторая функция - запустится при ошибке (reject)
      // alert("setOpen reject() return " + error); // error - аргумент reject
    }
  );
```